# batch file to move files only if folder has content

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have the following batch file set to move files periodically from one folder to another, but i noticed that if folder was empty and the batch script runs it actually move the folder itself.

So i want to check if folder is empty stop processing to prevent folder deletion else continue with script

```
@echo off



for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss"') do set 
datetime=%%a

echo copying file

 move C:\Shares\FTP\*.* 
 C:\Shares\FTPBackup\%datetime%".csv

echo done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to do this all in PowerShell. This requires the current Windows PowerShell 5.1+ or PowerShell Core. When you are confident that the correct directory will be created and the correct files moved, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `New-Item` and `Move-Item` commands.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Shares\FTP'
if ($Files.Count -gt 0) {
    $NewDir = 'C:\Shares\FTPBackup\$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss")'
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $NewDir)) { New-Item -ItemType 'Directory' -Path $NewDir -WhatIf | Out-Null }
    foreach ($File in $Files) {
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $NewDir -WhatIf
    }
}
```

If you are dead set committed to doing it as a cmd.exe script, something like this might work.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$Files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Shares\FTP';" ^
    "if ($Files.Count -gt 0) {" ^
        "$NewDir = 'C:\Shares\FTPBackup\$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss")';" ^
        "if (-not (Test-Path -Path $NewDir)) { New-Item -ItemType 'Directory' -Path $NewDir -WhatIf | Out-Null };" ^
        "foreach ($File in $Files) {" ^
            "Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $NewDir -WhatIf" ^
        "}" ^
    "}"
```

Comment: You may need further clarification lit. It is my understanding from what was posted that each of the files to be copied are CSV files and the OP wants each to be renamed with a basename of `yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss`. The important thing, if that is the case, is that the date and time string would be problematic if trying to to move more than one file during the same 'second' tick, due to overwrites, or failed moves.

Comment: @Compo, If that is what the OP wants, it would be generally useless. My interpretation was that all of the current files should go into a directory named with the current timestamp. I will just leave this here until the OP clarifies.